# =IF(ISERR(SEARCH query

Tags: excel

I have a formula which is =IF(ISERR(SEARCH("M004",$H26)),NA(), "G26"). I have multiple words in cells 'H26' of which I am trying to find 'M004' but I want the formula once it identifies M004 to input the value in G26, not 'True, False.... etc' Is this possible???

For example, 'In 'I26', I want see if H26 contains the value M004, if so I want the cell to equal the value in G26

Possible?

Forgot to ask, what do I type so if 'false' to leave box blank?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with `=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("M004",H26)),NA(), G26)`

Comment: Thanks a million, but forgot to ask, what do I type so if 'false' to leave box blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to leave the cell blank if N/A, do the following instead:

1. use `ISERROR` instead of `ISERR`: `ISERROR` will trap all error values, while `ISERR` will trap errors except #N/A
2. Change `NA()` to `""` to get a blank cell in case of an error.

   ```
   =IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("M004",H26)),"", G26)
   ```

I don't think getting `FALSE` is an option when you use `SEARCH()`, so you are covered for error cases when you use `ISERROR()`.

Comment: Thank you all again for help. Working!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation marks from around `"G26"` so that it is just `G26`

Also, here is an alternate formula that you can use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(H26,"*M004*")>0,G26,NA())
```

Comment: Thanks a million, but forgot to ask, what do I type so if 'false' to leave box blank?

Comment: Replace the `NA()` with `""`